# Making a randomly generated 2d map in python is taking too long to process all of the map generation

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
l =  "lava"
d = "dessert"
f = "forest"
v = "village"
s = "sect"
w = "water"
c = "city"
m = "mountains"
p = "plains"
t = "swamp"
map_list = [l,d,f,v,s,w,c,m,p,t]
map = []
for i in range(50):
    map.append([])

def rdm_map(x):
    for i in range(50):
        map[x].append(random.choice(map_list))

def map_create():
    x = 0
    while x <= len(map):
        rdm_map(x)
        x + 1

map_create()
print(map[2][1])
```

I'm not getting anything for output not even an error code.I'm trying to create a randomly generated game map of descent size but when i went to run it nothing happened i'm thinking since my computer isn't that great its just taking way to long to process but i just wanted to post it on here to double check. If that is the issue is there a way to lessen the load without lessening the map size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following bugs:

- Inside the map_create you must change `x + 1` to `x += 1`. For this reason your script runs for ever.
- After that you should change the `while x <= len(map):` to `while x < len(map):`. If you keep the previous, you will get a `Index Error`.

In any case, your code can be further improved. Please try to read some pages of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) first.

Comment: Interesting i thought that having that x <= len(map) part would keep it from running forever. I'll definitely be doing more research on the subject so I can understand the "why" of why i need those changes thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `x <= len(map)`, it will prevented from running for ever. But your initial code does not increment the `x`

Comment: The little light bulb just went on lol so just saying x + 1 does nothing i have to actually use the += to do the incrementation that i need for it to work and as far as the <= im guessing that the way it works that final x would actually be 1 longer than the actual len throwing that error?

Comment: Yes that's right. You are initiating the `map` list for 0 to 49, so you need to iterate with the same indexes and you should not go to the 50 item, because it does not exist